# Removing stop words from a Spark Dataframe

Tags: beginner, scala, natural-language-processing

I am trying to apply a function to two Spark Dataframes (in Zeppelin):

```
def RemoveStopwords (dfin : dataframe) : Dataframe = {
    val stopwords = 

    sc.textFile("/media/ed/Seagate/data/stopwords.txt")

    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
    val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(dfin)

    // remove stop words
    val remover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("NoStop")
    val dfNoStop= remover.transform(wordsData)

}
```

and I call it:

```
Array(dfHive, dfHive1).map(RemoveStopwords)
```

Is this the right way of doing things? Should I be passing in the `stopwords.txt` file rather than looking it up twice? Also, is it OK to have `: Dataframe` (some functions I have seen are declared `name : type` not just `: type`)?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anybody, I needed to do the following to fix my code:

1. add `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`
2. Make sure my DataFrame's were capitalized correctly.
3. add `dfNoStop` at the end of the function, to stop it returning unit.
4. make the call `val Array(dfNoStop, dfNoStop1)=Array(dfHive, dfHive1).map(RemoveStopwords)`